# Trying to understand jQuery nth-child

Tags: jquery

I currently have some trouble with understanding the nth-child selector in jQuery.

I have a list  that's defined as the following:

```
<ul class="nopadding nomargin" role="tablist">
  <li class="application inline" role="tab">
  <li id="tabHome" class="inline active" role="tab">
  <li id="tabSendReceive" class="inline" role="tab">
  <li id="tabFolder" class="inline" role="tab">
  <li id="tabView" class="inline" role="tab">
</ul>
```

You'll notice that the first LI element has an application class, while the others are not. Now, I'm writing an API that should be able to select a tab element based on its index.

This is the jQuery code for it:

```
EnableTabIndex : function(tabIndex) {
  console.log($("li[role=tab]:not(.application):nth-child(" + tabIndex + ")").attr("id"));
}
```

I'm justing using console.log here for testing purposes.
As far as my knowledge about jQuery goes, it should take the nth element which matches:

Now, for some strange reason, when I pass as tabIndex 2 the outcome is TabHome (the first tab element).

I don't understand why it is the second.

I could understand 0 or 1 (depending what value jQuery takes to start from - 0 or 1), but it should not be 2.

Can somebody explain me why this is happening?

Comment: `.index()` is still derived based on how it's nested (exempt of the disqualifying `:not()`)

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, can you explain why my retrieved index is 2 instead of 1 (which is should be according to me).

Comment: Just because you disqualify the `.application` node doesn't make "what's left" begin indexing. Regardless,  the first tab is still the second child is your list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `.eq()`, not `.nth-child()`. Why? Because as the [nth-child() docs](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) state, they're based on the CSS nth-child rules, and those rules only apply to elements, not classes of elements:

> Because jQuery's implementation of `:nth-` selectors is strictly derived
>   from the CSS specification, the value of `n` is "1-indexed", meaning
>   that the counting starts at 1. For other selector expressions such as
>   `:eq()` or `:even` jQuery follows JavaScript's "0-indexed" counting. Given
>   a single `<ul>` containing two `<li>`s, $( "li:nth-child(1)" ) selects the
>   first `<li>` while  $( "li:eq(1)" ) selects the second.
>
> The `:nth-child(n)` pseudo-class is easily confused with `:eq(n)`, even
>   though the two can result in dramatically different matched elements.
>   **With `:nth-child(n)`, all children are counted, regardless of what they
>   are**, and the specified element is selected only if it matches the
>   selector attached to the pseudo-class. With `:eq(n)` only the selector
>   attached to the pseudo-class is counted, not limited to children of
>   any other element, and the `(n+1)th` one (`n` is 0-based) is selected.

So:

```
console.log($("li[role=tab]:not('.application'):eq(2)").attr("id"));
```

will get you `tabFolder`, the element with index two (zero-based), absed on the role and `:not` filter you use.

Comment: I don't think the problem is the fact that it's one based. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24418544/227299

Comment: @JuanMendes - no, it's not that it's one based, it's that nth-child doesn't care about classes or roles.

Comment: I must have got your answer confused with [Barmar's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24418628/227299)

Answer (score 1):

That's because `nth-child` doesn't care about the rest of the selector. It will look at the rest of the selector if it is the nth child. It's not the nth child that matches the selector.

That is, to match `nth-child(1)`, the element has to be the first child of the parent, not the first child matching the rest of the query.

For example (http://jsfiddle.net/UQrze/)

```
<ul>
  <li class="a ">Test</li>
  <li class="a b">Test</li>
  <li class="a b">Test</li>
</ul>

/* Does not match because the first child doesn't contain a class of b */
li.b:nth-child(1) {
    color: red;    
}

/* Works since the second child does have the class of b */
li.b:nth-child(2) {
    color: red;    
}

li.b:nth-child(3) {
    color: red;    
}
```

Comment: And how can I take the nth-child that matches the selector?

Answer (score 0):

The `:nth-child` selector counts all children, regardless of other features of the selector. As stated in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/):

> The **:nth-child(n)** pseudo-class is easily confused with **:eq(n)**, even though the two can result in dramatically different matched elements. With **:nth-child(n)**, all children are counted, regardless of what they are, and the specified element is selected only if it matches the selector attached to the pseudo-class. With **:eq(n)** only the selector attached to the pseudo-class is counted, not limited to children of any other element, and the (n+1)th one (n is 0-based) is selected.

In other words, `SELECTOR:eq(n)` means:

> find all the elements that match SELECTOR, and choose the Nth one (zero-based).

But `SELECTOR:nth-child(n)` means:

> find all elements that are the Nth child of their parent (one-based), and choose the ones that also match SELECTOR.